# Custom script “Service invoked too many times for one day: route” error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am using the following functions on Google spreadsheet find travel time with traffic data between two locations or zip-code.

Inputs parameters would be from Location, destination, arrival time(this is between 6AM OR 8AM) Same script with different defined times

Based on the above input parameters in my google script function it should return travel time but I'm getting an error that Service invoked too many times for one day: route. (line 40). and I'm using the custom function below and there are 40 rows in my sheet.This is the function. Is there any way to make this an array formula? Would that help to avoid unnecessary calls ?

```js
function GetDuration(location1, location2, mode) {
  //var arrive = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (10 * 60 * 60 * 1000));//arrive in ten hours from now
 // var arrive=new Date(2019, 09, 07, 06);// 7th of September 2019 06:00 am
  var arrive = new Date();
  arrive.setHours(6,0,0,0);
  var directions  = Maps.newDirectionFinder().setArrive(arrive)
  .setOrigin(location1)
  .setDestination(location2)
  .setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode[mode])
  .getDirections();
  // Get a script lock, because we're about to modify a shared resource.
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  // Wait for up to 30 seconds for other processes to finish.
  lock.waitLock(20000);
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
 return directions.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix). It allows to perform a basic route search between multiple locations, it will not return the detailed route, but it has basic information on the routes, which I think will be enough for you.

You need to keep in mind that location services are paid, and your quotas depend on that. The link I provided also includes information on this and how to set it up.